# Reducing jitter in Android's WiFi direct communication using UDP transport protocol

Tags: java, android, udp, wifi-direct

I'm working on a real-time application that requires transmitting about 512 bytes of data every 5ms over a WiFi direct connection from a slave phone/s to a master (group owner). Average transmission delay is about 15ms, which is not that good, but the biggest issue is that I noticed a quite consistent pattern of periods where delay is as much as 100ms about every 2~3 seconds, plus periods of about 9 seconds every minute where throughput greatly reduces. Please take a look at the graph [scatter graph of delay over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFL2L.png). I also attached my socket programming code. Both master and slave internal clocks are synchronized within a 1ms error (don't worry about clock drift). 
Please let me know if you too have experienced these results and whether there is something that can be done to improve on this issue. Interestingly enough there is typically 0 data loss, and when a packet gets delayed all packets before it too (easy to see from the graph) even though this is UDP. I read somewhere that packets need to get acknowledged at the MAC layer even if UDP is used, and this is what might be causing delays of about 100ms.

The following is the code at the slave (sender):

```
public class DataTransmissionServiceV3 {

public static final String TAG = "DataTransmissionService";

private long mClockOffset;
private DatagramChannel mDatagramChannel;
private boolean running;

public void start(InetAddress remoteAddress, long clockOffset) {
    if (!running) {
        running = true;
        mClockOffset = clockOffset;
        Thread t = new Thread(new TransmissionTask(remoteAddress));
        t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        t.start();
    }
}

public void close() {
    running = false;
    if (mDatagramChannel != null) {
        mDatagramChannel.socket().close();
    }
}

private class TransmissionTask implements Runnable {

    private int mCount;
    private final ByteBuffer mByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            Constants.DATA_PACKET_SIZE);
    private final byte[] mBytes = new byte[Constants.DATA_PACKET_SIZE];
    private final InetAddress mRemoteAddress;

    public TransmissionTask(final InetAddress remoteAddress) {
        mRemoteAddress = remoteAddress;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            mDatagramChannel = DatagramChannel.open();
            mDatagramChannel.socket().connect(new InetSocketAddress(mRemoteAddress,
                    Constants.TRANS_MASTER_SERVER_PORT));
            mDatagramChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while connecting", ioe);
        }
        while (running) {
            TimeUtils.busyWait(5000000); // busy wait for 5ms
            send();
        }
    }

    private void send() {
        mCount++;
        DataPacket.setSequenceNumber(mBytes, mCount);
        DataPacket.setTimestamp(mBytes, TimeUtils.getTimestamp() + mClockOffset); // synchronized timestamp to master device to measure delay
        mByteBuffer.clear();
        mByteBuffer.put(mBytes);
        mByteBuffer.flip();
        try {
            mDatagramChannel.write(mByteBuffer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while sending data packet", e);
            running = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

And the following is the code at the master (receiver):

```
public class DataTransmissionServerV3 {

public static final String TAG = "DataTransmissionServer";

private DatagramChannel mDatagramChannel;
private boolean mRunning;
private Handler mHandler;

public DataTransmissionServerV3(Handler handler) {
    mHandler = handler;
}

public void start(InetAddress localAddress) {
    if (!mRunning) {
        mRunning = true;
        Thread t = new Thread(new ReceiveDataTask(localAddress));
        t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        t.start();
    }
}

public void close() {
    mRunning = false;
    if (mDatagramChannel != null) {
        mDatagramChannel.socket().close();
    }
}

private class ReceiveDataTask implements Runnable {

    private final InetAddress mLocalAddress;
    private final ByteBuffer mByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            Constants.DATA_PACKET_SIZE);
    private final byte[] mBytes = new byte[Constants.DATA_PACKET_SIZE];
    private int mCount;

    public ReceiveDataTask(final InetAddress localAddress) {
        mLocalAddress = localAddress;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            bind();
            while (mRunning) {
                receive();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while binding datagram socket", ioe);
        }
    }

    private void bind() throws IOException {
        mDatagramChannel = DatagramChannel.open();
        mDatagramChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(mLocalAddress,
                Constants.TRANS_MASTER_SERVER_PORT));
        mDatagramChannel.configureBlocking(true);
    }

    private boolean receive() {
        mByteBuffer.clear();
        try {
            SocketAddress isa = mDatagramChannel.receive(mByteBuffer);
            long t2 = TimeUtils.getTimestamp();
            if (isa != null) {
                mByteBuffer.flip();
                mByteBuffer.get(mBytes);
                mCount++;
                TransmissionStat stat = TransmissionStat.get(mBytes, mCount, t2);
                handlePacket(stat); // a statistic that is saved to file for later analysis (ignore this)
                return true;
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while receiving data", ioe);
            mRunning = false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void handlePacket(TransmissionStat stat) {
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.what = Constants.TRANSMISSION_PACKET_RECEIVED_CODE;
        msg.obj = stat;
        msg.sendToTarget();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, did you ever get to the bottom of this? I have a similar requirement though in trying with TCP packets every 33ms. I am sometimes seeing jitter - almost as if the packets are being buffered then sent as a burst a couple of seconds later.

Comment: I contacted Google to report it as a bug, and was told it is "intended behavior" for P2P type of connection. If you read WiFi Direct documentation [link](https://www.wi-fi.org/downloads-registered-guest/Wi-Fi%2BP2P%2BTechnical%2BSpecification%2Bv1.7.pdf/29559) you will see that they take some measures to save power both at client and GO, so likely this is what causes it. In Android Q beta version they added a new setting called low-latency mode, but it doesn't work with P2P connections, and is probably intended for connections through local network. Hope this helps.